# wait for function/tween to complete before calling another

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm writing an eCard in flash, and I want to sequence a series of animations after the user presses a button. The first is a shape tween playing on lines 2-60 of MovieClip displayScreen_mc. The second, is a function in a separate class I wrote called TypeWriter, and it writes strings out one letter at a time on a TLFTextField. (That code is working perfectly.)

The problem: I want to iterate through a string array. At each iteration, I want to gotoAndPlay, then use the TypeWriter to write out the string. The code I have follows:

```
var greetings:Array = new Array( "string 1, string2, string3, etc " );

//Onclick functiont to start sequence of events..
function displayInvitation(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var tw = new TypeWriter();
    var index:int = 0;
    while ( index < greetings.length )
    {
        displayStatic(); 
        tw.writeText(greetings[index], 100, displayScreen_mc.displayText);
        index++;
    }
}

function displayStatic():void
{
    displayScreen_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

These are all written in the actionscript of an Actions layer on my stage. TypeWriter is a separate class containing the writeText function. I want displayStatic to finish before tw.textWrite is called. I'd like to keep gotoAndPlay inside a function, because I may want to add some things there in the future.

I've been trying to use an addEventListener to wait for completion of the first function before calling the second. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to introduce an ENTER_FRAME listener into your code and test for the certain conditions to complete before continuing. I'm not sure that the example will do exactly what you want (hard to tell what the other participants do) and I haven't tested it but it may give you some ideas.

Eg.

```
var greetings = [ "..." ];
var index:int;
var tw:TypeWriter;

function displayInvitation(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    index = 0;
    tw = new TypeWriter();
    addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onProcessEnterFrame );
}


function onProcessEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    if( index < greetings.length )
    {
        if( displayScreen_mc.currentFrame == displayScreen_mc.totalFrames )
        {
            displayStatic();
            tw.writeText(greetings[index], 100, displayScreen_mc.displayText);
            index++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
         removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onProcessEnterFrame );
         // greetings displayed
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Not exactly. displayScreen_mc is a movieclip which has a shape tween on frames 2-60, and it has a TLFTextField named displayText. 

The line 
`tw.writeText(greetings[index], 100, displayScreen_mc.displayText);` 
could be substituted with: 
`displayScreen_mc.dislayText.text = greetings[index];`

Comment: But what I want to do, is delay `tw.writeText()` until after displayScreen_mc  reaches frame 60.   However, I'd like to leave it less explicit then ENTER_FRAME, if possible. Something like an Event.COMPLETE eventListener. I'm also a complete newb to Flash, so please excuse me if my thinking is flawed here..

Answer (score 0):

On the last frame of displayScreen_mc tween, dispatch an event such as "animationEnd" and listen for the event to start your textWrite function. In code:

Inside displayScreen_mc on the last frame:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("animationEnd"));
```

On your main stage:

```
displayScreen_mc.addEventListener("animationEnd", writeText);
function writeText(e:Event):void{
    tw.textWrite(/*arguments*/);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. For some reason, both the tween and the writeText are starting simultaneously...

Comment: @Logan Danger Black Did you update your code? If so, could you please post it?